# Google Maps centering or marker positioning issue

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I develop a simple Google Maps application. I need just to place one marker on the map. For whatever reason, the marker is placed outside of the visible area of the map. It's a little bit strange, because the map is centered to the marker's coordinates. Here is the code:

```
var point1 = new GLatLng(location1.lat,location1.lon);              
    map1.setCenter(point1, 15);
var marker1 = new GMarker(point1);
map1.addOverlay(marker1);
map1.setCenter(point1);
```

When we drag the map  a little bit, we can see the marker. What do I need is to center the map in the way the marker will be visible without map dragging.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I had this happen to me when the div that contained the maps was not of the same size as the GMap2, because of rescaling in the onLoad of the page.

Comment: Is it possible that location1.lat and location1.lon are String objects, rather then Numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the GLatLng object would accept String arguments as well - but to be safe I would ensure that they are integers - try using:

```
new GLatLng(parseInt(location.lat), parseInt(location.lon));
```

I also noticed you call map.setCenter a second time which ought to not be necessary.

Using the following code really ought to do it

```
  map=new GMap(document.getElementById("map"));
  var point = new GLatLng(parseInt(location.lat), parseInt(location.lon));
  map.setCenter(point,5);
  var marker = new GMarker(point);
  map.addOverlay(marker);
```

If you still are having issues I would check that "location" object to make sure the .lat and .lon values are being populated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code out:

```
var map = new GMap(document.getElementById("map"));
/* -- snip -- */
map.centerAndZoom(new GPoint(-1.2736, 53.0705), 8);
```

From a website I made a while ago. Feel free to check the source:

http://www.primrose-house.co.uk/localattractions

Just click the link in the top right to switch to the map view.